# Issue while deploying JDK 17 and Spring 6 application in Tomcat 10.1.20

Tags: java, spring

Application migrated from Spring 5 to String 6 and JDK 1.8 to 17.
The application is running in STS using the embedded Tomcat 10.1.15.
But when I deploy the application to a Tomcat server 10.1.20 we are getting the following error.

`org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setFilterChains' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'securityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [com/xx/app1/security/SecurityConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain]: Factory method 'securityFilterChain' threw exception with message: This method cannot decide whether these patterns are Spring MVC patterns or not. If this endpoint is a Spring MVC endpoint, please use requestMatchers(MvcRequestMatcher); otherwise, please use requestMatchers(AntPathRequestMatcher).

This is because there is more than one mappable servlet in your servlet context: {org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet=[*.jspx, *.jsp], org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet=[/]}.

For each MvcRequestMatcher, call MvcRequestMatcher#setServletPath to indicate the servlet path.
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.resolveMethodArguments(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:875) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:828) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:145) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:492) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1416) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:597) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:973) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:950) ~[spring-context-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:616) ~[spring-context-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:738) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:440) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:174) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:154) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:96) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:171) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4880) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.20]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.20]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:683) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.20]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:658) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.20]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:712) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.20]
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:969) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.20]
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1911) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.20]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-util.jar:10.1.20]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:123) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:771) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.20]
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:423) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.20]
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1629) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.20]
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:303) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.20]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:114) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.20]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:402) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.20]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:345) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.20]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:893) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.20]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:845) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.20]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.20]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1332) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.20]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1322) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.20]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-util.jar:10.1.20]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:866) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.20]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:240) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.20]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.20]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:433) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.20]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.20]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:921) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.20]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.20]
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:757) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.20]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:345) ~[bootstrap.jar:10.1.20]
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:473) ~[bootstrap.jar:10.1.20]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [com/xx/app1/security/SecurityConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain]: Factory method 'securityFilterChain' threw exception with message: This method cannot decide whether these patterns are Spring MVC patterns or not. If this endpoint is a Spring MVC endpoint, please use requestMatchers(MvcRequestMatcher); otherwise, please use requestMatchers(AntPathRequestMatcher).

This is because there is more than one mappable servlet in your servlet context: {org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet=[*.jspx, *.jsp], org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet=[/]}.

For each MvcRequestMatcher, call MvcRequestMatcher#setServletPath to indicate the servlet path.
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:654) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:642) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1332) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1162) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:560) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.addCandidateEntry(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1633) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1597) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveMultipleBeans(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1488) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1375) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1337) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.resolveMethodArguments(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:867) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
... 61 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain]: Factory method 'securityFilterChain' threw exception with message: This method cannot decide whether these patterns are Spring MVC patterns or not. If this endpoint is a Spring MVC endpoint, please use requestMatchers(MvcRequestMatcher); otherwise, please use requestMatchers(AntPathRequestMatcher).

This is because there is more than one mappable servlet in your servlet context: {org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet=[*.jspx, *.jsp], org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet=[/]}.

For each MvcRequestMatcher, call MvcRequestMatcher#setServletPath to indicate the servlet path.
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:171) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:650) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
... 77 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: This method cannot decide whether these patterns are Spring MVC patterns or not. If this endpoint is a Spring MVC endpoint, please use requestMatchers(MvcRequestMatcher); otherwise, please use requestMatchers(AntPathRequestMatcher).

This is because there is more than one mappable servlet in your servlet context: {org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet=[*.jspx, *.jsp], org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet=[/]}.

For each MvcRequestMatcher, call MvcRequestMatcher#setServletPath to indicate the servlet path.
at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.AbstractRequestMatcherRegistry.requestMatchers(AbstractRequestMatcherRegistry.java:208) ~[spring-security-config-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.AbstractRequestMatcherRegistry.requestMatchers(AbstractRequestMatcherRegistry.java:276) ~[spring-security-config-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
at com.xx.app1.security.SecurityConfiguration.lambda$securityFilterChain$0(SecurityConfiguration.java:40) ~[classes/:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity.authorizeHttpRequests(HttpSecurity.java:1466) ~[spring-security-config-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
at com.xx.app1.security.SecurityConfiguration.securityFilterChain(SecurityConfiguration.java:39) ~[classes/:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
at com.xx.app1.security.SecurityConfiguration$$SpringCGLIB$$0.CGLIB$securityFilterChain$1() ~[classes/:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
at com.xx.app1.security.SecurityConfiguration$$SpringCGLIB$$FastClass$$1.invoke() ~[classes/:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:258) ~[spring-core-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331) ~[spring-context-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at com.xx.app1.security.SecurityConfiguration$$SpringCGLIB$$0.securityFilterChain() ~[classes/:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:139) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
... 78 common frames omitted

31-Mar-2024 19:33:43.436 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Error deploying web application archive [C:\Projects\Softwares\apache-tomcat-10.1.20\webapps\app1-back.war]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error starting child
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:686)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:658)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:712)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:969)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1911)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:771)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:423)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1629)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:114)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:402)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:345)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:893)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:845)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1332)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1322)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:866)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:433)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:921)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:757)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:345)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:473)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/app1-back]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:419)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:186)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:683)
... 37 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setFilterChains' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'securityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [com/xx/app1/security/SecurityConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain]: Factory method 'securityFilterChain' threw exception with message: This method cannot decide whether these patterns are Spring MVC patterns or not. If this endpoint is a Spring MVC endpoint, please use requestMatchers(MvcRequestMatcher); otherwise, please use requestMatchers(AntPathRequestMatcher).

This is because there is more than one mappable servlet in your servlet context: {org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet=[*.jspx, *.jsp], org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet=[/]}.

For each MvcRequestMatcher, call MvcRequestMatcher#setServletPath to indicate the servlet path.
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.resolveMethodArguments(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:875)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:828)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:145)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:492)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1416)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:597)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:973)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:950)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:616)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:738)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:440)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:174)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:154)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:96)
at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4880)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
... 38 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [com/xx/app1/security/SecurityConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain]: Factory method 'securityFilterChain' threw exception with message: This method cannot decide whether these patterns are Spring MVC patterns or not. If this endpoint is a Spring MVC endpoint, please use requestMatchers(MvcRequestMatcher); otherwise, please use requestMatchers(AntPathRequestMatcher).

`

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfiguration {
    
    private final JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter;
    
    private final UserService userService;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(
                        request -> request.requestMatchers("/**").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated())
                .sessionManagement(manager -> manager.sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS))
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider())
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        http.cors();
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userService.userDetailsService());
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration config) throws Exception {
        return config.getAuthenticationManager();
    }
}
```

Any help will be appeciated.

Comment: This issue is resolved, it was related to AuthenticationEntryPoint